# "Обломать" порт при достижении определенного числа запросов

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, port

Как автоматически "обломать" порт при достижении 20 запросов в минуту в debian? Думаю, это возможно сделать с помощью iptables

Comment: Есть модуль [limit](https://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/iptables-how-to-use-the-limits-module/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так (для *новых* соединений):

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport nash_port -m limit --limit 20/minute --limit-burst 1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport nash_port -j REJECT
```

Посмотрите `man iptables-extensions` на предмет limit и limit-burst.